# Ajax call not displaying message properly using Yii framework

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

So here's the problem:

Trying to make an ajax call using .ajax.  However, there's something going wrong somewhere because my controller isn't redirecting to the good view file and nothing is displaying on my page.

Here is where the ajax call happens

```
        $('#validate').on('click',function(){
        var data = []; // data container
        // collect all the checked checkboxes and their associated attributes
        $("table#subsection_table input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
            data.push({
                subsectionid : $(this).val(),
                sectionid : $(this).data('sectionid'),
                year : $(this).data('year')
           })
       });
        // JSON it so that it can be passed via Ajax call to a php page
        var data = JSON.stringify(data);


        $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("scheduler/AjaxExample"); ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data : "myData=" + data,
            success : function()
            {
                alert("in success");
                $("#ajax-results").html(data);
                $("#ajax-results").dialog({ width: 500, height: 500})
            },
            error: function()
            {
                alert("there was an error")
            }
        })
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

        $('#dialog').html(data).dialog({ width: 500, heigh: 500});
    });
```

Now here's my controller code:

```
          public function actionAjaxExample()
{
    $post_data = $_POST['myData'];



    $this->renderPartial('_ajax', array(
            'data'=> $post_data,
        )
    );

}
```

trying to redirect to _ajax view file:

```
          <?php

           echo '<script language="javascript">';
           echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
           echo '</script>';
           echo "HI FROM BACKEND! here's what you gave to PHP: <br>";
           print_r($data);
           ?>
```

So I'm obviously doing something wrong but... I can't seem to find where because the ajax call  DOES happen ( at least in my #validate on click event). However, the last view file isn't displaying it's alert box OR the "hello from back end".

Comment: could you check that the url given by your code: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("scheduler/AjaxExample"); ?>" is correct?

Comment: as well, your method AjaxExample() must be accesible in case you defined a filter() with accessControl enabled. In your js code you are not passing the response data to the success function, do something like: `success : function( response )
            {
                alert("in success");
                alert(response); 
               ... 
            } ` so you can check the server response easily.

Comment: Oh my i forgot to do function ( data).  For the access control,  I read that it is only if I'm using accessRules() in my file which I'm not ( I don't think I am anyways, I am rather new to Yii).  As for the AjaxExample, it is situated under Protected -> Controller -> SchedulerController -> actionAjaxExample. Otherwise it would  give me a 404 url not found in my console no?

Comment: Check also the controller code, make sure how php receives the data, use something like: `public function actionAjaxExample()
{ print_r($_POST); }` so you can properly use the data you send.

Comment: try `$this->renderPartial('_viewfile', $data, false, true);` try to set fourth parameter as true for processed output

Answer (score 0):

Try :
remove `var data = JSON.stringify(data);`

change

```
data:{myData:data},
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the quotes of the url.
Please check if you are getting some JavaScript error in console.
If you are getting some error, Please change this

```
 $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("scheduler/AjaxExample"); ?>",
        type: "POST",
```

to

```
$.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("scheduler/AjaxExample"); ?>',
        type: "POST",
```

If not getting any error, Please check the xHr tab in console, whats the url, your ajax is hitting. Please let me know in case of any issue